# Keyboard and drawviews

Tags: android, keyboard, draw

I have a big problem, I draw a line between 2 points with onDraw and then I put a tag name behind th line, I use dynamic inputtext with an alert dialogue the problem is when the input finish and the alertdialogue disappear the draw dissapear as well, I'm frustrated with this problem.

I tried doing all kind of manipulation it didn't work .
this is how I draw:

```
DrawView drawView = new DrawView(maps.this);
drawView.setId(links[calculator2[0]]);

savelinks[calculator2[0]][0]= clickat[0];
savelinks[calculator2[0]][1]= clickat[1];
savelinks[calculator2[0]][2]= clickat[2];
savelinks[calculator2[0]][3]= clickat[3];
savelinks[calculator2[0]][4]= thecolore[0];
thidrawres[calculator2[0]]=drawView;

RelativeLayout mapView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlayou);
mapView.addView(drawView);
```

Comment: You're going to have to share more code.  For example we have no idea what a DrawView is, it isn't a standard class.  Although I will say adding a view to a RelativeLayout without layout parameters is a risky move.

Comment: i found a solution just 5 min after posting the question hhhhh thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Here's the class DrawView

```
class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);

            paint.setColor(colorr[thecolore[0]]);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawLine(clickat[0], clickat[1], clickat[2], clickat[3], paint);

                            clickat[0] = -1;
                            clickat[1] = -1;
                            clickat[2] = -1;
                            clickat[3] = -1;
```